# Unable to change values in a function

Tags: c++

I'm starting with developing, sorry about this newbie question.

I need to create a function that swap values between 2 vars.

I have wrote this code, but no changes are made in vars, What should I change? What is my mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap_values( int x, int y);
int main(void) {
   int a,b;    
   a = 2;   
   b = 5;  
   cout << "Before: " << a << " " << b << endl; 
   swap_values( a,b );   
   cout << "After: " << a << " " << b  << endl;   
}  
void swap_values( int x, int y ){
   int z;
   z = y;
   y = x;
   x = z;
}
```

Comment: Using the already existing `std::swap` is not an option?

Comment: @BoPersson, thanks, but just homeworks. To understand it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the variables by reference:

```
void swap_values( int& x, int& y )
{
   int z;
   z = y;
   y = x;
   x = z;
}
```

`pass-by-value` and `pass-by-reference` are key concepts in major programming languages. In C++, unless you specify by-reference, a `pass-by-value` occurs.

It basically means that it's not the original variables that are passed to the function, but copies.

That's why, outside the function, the variables remained the same - because inside the functions, only the copies were modified.

If you pass by reference (`int& x, int& y`), the function operates on the original variables.

Comment: Thanks about clearly answer. My teacher talks about `void swap_values( int *x, int *y )`. What this means? Congratulations about 15K R!!!

Comment: That's passing by pointer. It's basically the same outcome, only that you need to pass the addresses of your variables to the function instead of the variables themselves, like in pass-by-reference. By passing the addresses, you will work with the same memory inside the function, so any changes to the **memory pointed to by the pointers** (not to the pointers themselves) will reflect outside the function.

Comment: @CrazyHorse also, not at 15k yet, I have 14960 :), SO just rounds up the number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that by default, C++ use a call-by-value calling convention.

When you call `swap_values`, its stack frame receives a copy of the values passed to it as parameters. Thus, the parameters `int x, int y` are completely independent of the caller, and the variables `int a, b`.

Fortunately for you, C++ also support call-by-reference (see wikipedia, or a good programming language design textbook on that), which essentially means that the variables in your function are bound to (or, an alias of) the variables in the caller (this is a gross simplification).

The syntax for call-by-reference is:

```
void swap_values( int &x, int &y ){
    // do your swap here
}
```

Comment: No idea, looks correct to me. Maybe they had a problem with "by default, C++ uses by value calling convention" because there is no default, you have to explicitly specify how you want every parameter passed. But that's a little too pedantic a reason to downvote for IMO.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: But, it is in fact the default to use call-by-value - you need to annotate your arguments to receive any other behaviour.

Comment: Didn't Downvote but *the variables in your function are bound to the variables in the caller* should be *the variables in your function are alias of the variables in the caller*. That is more suitable I think.As for the downvote, don't bother, haters can only hate.

Comment: Yeah, it's a stretch, but you need to annotate your arguments (with nothing...) to do pass-by-value as well. Also you can use `typedef`s to avoid explicitly writing it. Anyway, that might not even be the reason for the downvote though, a comment from Downvoter would be helpful.

Comment: @Als: I think they're equivalent, but I've updated to reflect both formulae.

Comment: +1 because this is correct, unlike using pointers, an answer which got +2 votes and isn't even pass by reference. I'd also like to know the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing by value. you can still pass by value but need to work with pointers.

here is the correct code needed:

```
void swap(int *i, int *j) {
   int t = *i;
   *i = *j;
   *j = t;
}

void main() {
   int a = 23, b = 47;
   printf("Before. a: %d, b: %d\n", a, b);
   swap(&a, &b);
   printf("After . a: %d, b: %d\n", a, b);
}
```

also a small document that explains "by reference" vs "by value" : http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1232/c-pointers-pass-by-value-pass-by-reference/

Comment: You don't need pointers to pass by reference, see my answer. Also, your snippet doesn't pass by reference. It also passes by value, only that it's the pointer that gets passed by value.

Comment: Although this is almost equivalent to pass-by-reference (ie it achieves the same effect), this is pass-by-value of pointers to the variables.

Comment: This is not pass-by-reference.